# How do i use joined() function after using sorted() in swift?

Tags: swift, sorting

```
let var1 = "AnyCode".sorted()
print(var1.joined(separator:""))
```

**ERROR: No exact matches in call to instance method 'joined'**

I am trying to join the array after sorting the string. = "AnyCode"

I was expecting the output was = ACdenoy

But it is giving an error.

Comment: If you put your mouse over `var1`, what's its type? it's a `[String.Element]` (~array of characters). But if you look at the doc of `joined(separator:)` it says: `Available when Element is String.` which isn't your case, hence the error.

Comment: Welcome to the wild and wacky world of Swift strict types! :) Not to mention the rather uninformative error messages...

Answer (score 4):

A Swift `String` is a collection of `Character`s, and `sorted()` applied to a collection returns an *array* with the collection elements in sorted order.

So `var1` has the type `[Character]`, and you can simply create a new string from that array with:

```
let var1 = "AnyCode".sorted()
print(String(var1)) // ACdenoy
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Martin R's answer (but not better than that answer), you might have said

```
print(var1.map(String.init).joined())
```

...turning the characters to strings before trying to join the array elements.